# How to map a column of sample ID's to their respective filename

Tags: r, string, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe which contains a column called sample_id amongst other metadata.

```
df <- data.frame(sample_id = c('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'))
```

I also have a list of files that contain their respective filenames which might not always have the same suffix.

```
files <- list('x1_001.txt', 'x2_003.txt', 'x4_abc.txt', 'x3_bg.txt')
```

I'd like to create a column in the data frame that greps the filename from the list of files and maps it to the respective sample_id.

However when I try to do that with `df <- df %>% mutate(filename = grep(sample_id, files, value = TRUE)` it doesn't work.

Is there a function that has this capability or would I need to create something custom?

Thank you for any help.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(filename = grep(sample_id, files, value = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another base R option might be using `max.col` + `adist`

```
transform(
  data.frame(sample_id = c("x1", "x2", "x3")),
  filename = (v1 <- unlist(files))[max.col(-adist(sample_id, v1, fixed = FALSE))]
)
```

which gives

```
  sample_id   filename
1        x1 x1_001.txt
2        x2 x2_003.txt
3        x3  x3_bg.txt
```

Comment: What if the lists were of unequal lengths? Let's say df$sample_id only contained x1, x2, and x3. This situation didn't work when I tried it.

Comment: @APompetti-Cori Sorry that I had a typo in my solution. You can retry with my updated example and solution.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to extract the substring from the file names with `sub` and do a `match` with the 'sample_id' column and then reorder the files based on the numeric index

```
v1 <- unlist(files)
df$filename <- v1[match(df$sample_id, sub( "_.*", "", v1))]
```

-output

```
> df
  sample_id   filename
1        x1 x1_001.txt
2        x2 x2_003.txt
3        x3  x3_bg.txt
4        x4 x4_abc.txt
```

Comment: What if it is not easy to extract the substring from the file names? Let's say x1 has a file name of x1_001.txt and abc2 has a file name of abc2-L002_R1.txt

Comment: @APompetti-Cori It depends on the pattern .  With your new example, it would be `v1 <- c("x1_001.txt", "abc2-L002_R1.txt");
> sub("[-_].*", "", v1)#
[1] "x1"   "abc2"`

Comment: @APompetti-Cori changing the rules after you get the solution is not very good